# easier way to get the result as shown by following sql query (oracle database)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Can anybody let us know an easier way to get the result as shown by following query? We need to find a way that can show us the same result as the following query:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT A.bio_id ,
    DECODE(A.wk_units2 - B.wk_units1,0,NULL,A.wk_units2) prev,
    DECODE(A.wk_units2 - B.wk_units1,0,NULL,B.wk_units1) curr, 
    DECODE(A.wk_units3 -B.wk_units2,0,NULL,A.wk_units3) prev, 
    DECODE(A.wk_units3 -B.wk_units2,0,NULL,B.wk_units2) curr, 
    DECODE(A.wk_units4 -B.wk_units3,0,NULL,A.wk_units4) prev, 
    DECODE(A.wk_units4 -B.wk_units3,0,NULL,B.wk_units3) curr,
    DECODE(A.wk_units5 -B.wk_units4,0,NULL,A.wk_units5) prev, 
    DECODE(A.wk_units5 -B.wk_units4,0,NULL,B.wk_units4) curr, 
    DECODE(A.wk_units6 -B.wk_units5,0,NULL,A.wk_units6) prev, 
    DECODE(A.wk_units6 -B.wk_units5,0,NULL,B.wk_units5) curr 
     .                                            .
     .                                            .
     .                                            .
   DECODE(A.wk_units105 -B.wk_units104,0,NULL,A.wk_units105) prev, 
   DECODE(A.wk_units105 -B.wk_units105,0,NULL,B.wk_units104) curr 



    FROM 
    cnt_sls_dm.fct_sales_summary A,
    cnt_sls_dm.fct_sales_summary B 
    WHERE 
    A.bio_id=B.bio_id AND A.bio_id<>0 
    AND ROWNUM<25 
    AND ( A.wk_units2<> B.wk_units1 
    OR  A.wk_units3<> B.wk_units2 
    OR  A.wk_units4<> B.wk_units3 
    OR  A.wk_units5<> B.wk_units4 
    OR  A.wk_units6<> B.wk_units5
     .                        .
     .                        .
     .                        .
    OR  A.wk_units105<>B.wk_units104)
```

The output is like:

```
    BIO_ID  PREV    CURR    PREV_1  CURR_1  PREV_2  CURR_2  PREV_3  CURR_3
5,032,130.00    -1  0   0   1           0   1
5,032,130.00    1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1
5,032,130.00            0   1           0   1
5,032,130.00            10  1   10  0   0   1
5,032,328.00    53  0   36  0   20  0       
5,032,328.00                            1   0
5,175,147.00    2   0                       
5,175,147.00            2   0               
5,175,147.00                                
21,073,129.00   17  0                   2   0
21,073,129.00   18  0   6   0   2   0       
21,073,129.00                           1   0
21,073,129.00                           3   0
21,073,129.00
```

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: @Irveen; You shall provide feedback if the suggested solution works / to answer additional questions.

Comment: @Irveen: what do you mean by "easier"?  If you want us to rewrite the query you should describe the rules for generating the result and provide an explanation for the nastily denormalised table.

Comment: i am using oracle 10g
--
yeah need to write a sql query with a loop so that it can get us data for week 1 - week 105..............means we need to implement iteration in current sql query

Comment: can any body suggest how to implement it through procedure,function or package

Answer (score 1):

I'd change the part

```
AND ( A.wk_units2<> B.wk_units1 
OR  A.wk_units3<> B.wk_units2 
OR  A.wk_units4<> B.wk_units3  ...
```

to

```
AND NOT ( A.wk_units2 == B.wk_units1 
OR A.wk_units3== B.wk_units2 
...
```

as it may be faster. But I've no idea to circumvent the DECODE stuff.